# obout tree view update from 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, obout

Please advice if there are any significant changes to do in my coding (C# and JS) when  I upgrade to new treeview (Obout.Ajax.UI 2.11.1026 in .net 3.5) from am using the old Treeview (from assembly obout_ASPTreeView_2_NET 2.0.41 in .net 2.0)

We are using:
- Load on demand using auxiliary page.
- Virtual scrolling.

Notes:

1. The C# code changes looks relative easy and server callback (that eliminates the need for auxiliary page) looks handy.
2. I am after possible gotchas to avoid and/or significant code changes (e.g. Server callback)
3. There is no sample code for virtual scrolling in version 2.11 (the website shows a demo for version 2.0.41)

Answer (score 2):

I have this answer from Obout support:

> The new [`Obout.Ajax.UI.TreeView`](http://www.obout.com/obout.ajax.ui/treeview/docs/OboutTree.aspx) is completely different than the old obout_ASPTreeView_2_NET control. Unfortunately there is no easy way to upgrade from one to the other. If the old version works fine for you, I'd recommend not to upgrade to the new one.

Thus, do not upgrade unless you are using it in new pages.